# MySQL IF THEN ELSE statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a terrible time understanding the MySQL documentation on using the IF statements I am hoping someone can simplify it for me. I don't even know if what I want to accomplish is best done using the MySQL IF statements or if there is a better way to do it using PHP. I am attempting to create an online time card system just for learning/experimenting for now. I have three buttons "Clock in" "Update" and "Clock Out". "Clock in" is pretty straight forward all I do is add "Employee ID" and "Time in" along with "Date" to the table. The "Update" function is where I am at now. So what I am looking to do with it is:

1. Add several PHP variables to specified columns in table.
2. Add the current time to the "time out" column.
3. Add the current time to the "time in" column in a new row with same "employee ID".

So the statement I want to make is going to be something like:

```
IF "timeOut" is NULL
WHERE "employeeID" AND "currentDate"
THEN 
UPDATE "timeRecords" SET "jobDescription", "timeOut"
WHERE "employeeID" AND "currentDate"
THEN
INSERT "timeIn", "employeeID", "currentDate"
```

Is there even a way to write this in MySQL? If so could someone give me an example of a working MySQL statement the documentation does not provide enough for me to understand it.
Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this I am missing?

Comment: What would you suggest doing then

Comment: Please post expected contents of the table before and after clicking "Update"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using if/then statements in your SQL at all.  "control structurs" are for languages like C, PHP or Java -SQL is about "sets".

In this particular case, look at the mysql "Replace" statement.  It's probably *ideal* for your scenario ("if new, then insert; else update"):

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html
- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx

  REPLACE INTO table_name(column_name1,column_name2,…) VALUES(value1,value2,…)

Comment: Look again - his question is about calling a MySQL RDBMS from PHP.  Specifically, he wants to do a so-called "upsert".  One good answer is the MySQL command "replace".  Here are some other alternatives: http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2009/06/approaches-to-upsert.html